# Laravel 4,eloquent mysql table design issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent

I want to be able to design a database which has the following;

```
 customer
 --------------
 id(int) | name

 Company
 -------------------------
 id(int) | name | location 

 queue
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id (datetime-primary but not auto-increment) | company_id | customer_id | position (not primary but auto-increment)

 customer_queue
 -----------------------
 customer_id | queue_id

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('queues', function(Blueprint $table)
   {
    $table->dateTime('id')->primary();  //dateTime for id since one is genereated every other working day
    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
        $table->increments('position');
        $table->time('start_time');
        $table->time('end_start');
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->time('joined_at');
        $table->time('left_at');
        $table->integer('customer_queue_status');
        $table->timestamps();
    //$table->primary(array('id', 'position'));
    });
    //find a way to make position auto-increment without being primary and rather set id to primary without auto-incrementing
}
```

I'm using laravel 4 with eloquent and it doesn't allow me to specify only primary for id in queue table and then make position auto-increment without being primary.

The error i get is as follows

```
>This is the error i get
>[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary ke  
  y defined (SQL: alter table `queues` add primary key queues_id_primary(`id`  
  ))
```

Comment: please post your current migration/setup and the code of your Queue model

Comment: @MatthiasS thank you for your response. I have added the queue migration but there's no code in the queue model yet. as the database is still not working.

Comment: You should rethink your model.  Auto increment is limited to primary keys.  You'll need to increment position yourself using PHP.

Comment: @dave thank you for your suggestion however, i need the id field to be datetime and not int or auto-incremented it can be unique as it is only changed or a new one is created every other day.

Comment: i read elsewhere that stating protected $primaryKey = 'id'; in the model will work. I can also make the id key unique which will cause it to be indexed. Is a combination of these two going to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Increments will automatically try to set the field as a primary key. Therefore you can not use  it to increment your position automatically. 
If your id field is set to primary, it is by definition unique.

I think there is no way around implementing the auto-increment on your own.
I would do it in some way like this, in your Queue model:

```
 class Queue extends Eloquent {
    //....
    public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

      static::creating(function($queue) {
        $position = DB::table('queues')->max('position');
        if(is_null($position)) $position = 0;
        $position++;
        $queue->position = $position;
        return true;

      });
    }
   //....
 }
```

This way everytime you save your `Queue` model it should look for the highest value and increment that by one. In case you have no entry yet it will start with 1.
In your schema, set `$table->integer('position')->unique();`